# Enable core dumps for all applications started by a user with systemd

Tags: opensuse, systemd, core-dump

This is a follow-up to [How to enable crash reports/core dumps/stack trace logging globally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31187/9454): How can I achieve this on OpenSUSE 13.1 (which uses systemd) and 13.2 for all processes started from an X-session (or even globally)?

Earlier versions of OpenSUSE supported setting `ulimit` via `/etc/sysconfig/ulimit`, but that's not used anymore in 13.1. I want to debug crashes of `xload`, which is started from my KDE session. `sudo systemd-coredumpctl` reportes no coredumps.

I have added the line

```
DefaultLimitCORE=infinity
```

in `/etc/systemd/user.conf`, but that gives me only cores of some programs, not of the `xload`s started by me.

See also [this thread](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-factory/2014-08/msg00478.html) on the opensuse mailing list.